# Ctags - only show relevant or contextual tags

Tags: vim, ctags

I have a working Ctags setup with Vim.
My current settings are as follows:

```
set tags=./tags;/
set tags+=~/.ctags/*/tags
```

which basically looks up for a `tags` file in the current directory and up until `/`, and also looks up for `tags` inside `~/.ctags` directory, where I have `tags` sorted for different projects in different directories.

Now, everything is working fine except when:
- I have two tag files defined as: `~/.ctags/ruby/tags` and `~/.ctags/php/tags`
- and I am working in a PHP project and `CTRL+]` takes me to a tag for a Ruby project (due to the second rule defined above) - when I expected it to search for a relevant tag inside `~/.ctags/php/tags` - it instead found a match inside `~/.ctags/ruby/tags` - and hence, the behaviour.

So, can I ask Vim to only look up inside `~/.ctags/php/tags` when I am working in PHP, only look up `~/.ctags/ruby/tags` when I am working in ruby, and lets say `~/.ctags/xxxx/tags` when I am working in `xxxx`

Regards

Comment: It is true that Vim does not distinguish between tags of different languages. But this is only part of the problem. It also does not use context to figure out the relevant tags within the same language, like any decent IDE would do. Not sure why there are not plugins that achieve this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I have done it in my `.vimrc` file is by setting a local `tags` variable:

```
augroup TagFileType
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType * setl tags<
    autocmd FileType * exe 'setl tags+=~/.ctags/' . &filetype . '/tags'
augroup END
```

What this does: whenever you open a file it copies the current contents of the global `tags` variable to the local `tags` variable, and adds `~/.ctags/[filetype]/tags` to it. This means that in a php buffer only `~/.ctags/php/tags` would be searched, and in a ruby buffer `~/.ctags/ruby/tags`. If you have any tags you want to be searched in all buffers you can set the global `tags` variable to point to those, and they will be loaded in all buffers.

Answer (score 2):

Daan's solution looks nice.

You might want to take a look at the [easytags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags) plugin which autogenerates tags. It can optionally be based on the filetype.